# React curly braces inside quotes to ads className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a class name if a button is clicked

```js
className={"collapse"+{active? "expand":null}}
```

If a button is clicked i want to add a class name **expand** along with **collapse** . But I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: Did you intend that to be a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> className={`collpase ${active ? "expand" : undefined}`}

Answer (score 0):

While this won't work:

```js
className={"collapse" + {active ? "expand" : null}}
```

This will:

```
className={"collapse" + active ?  "expand" : null}
```

The curly braces you used are syntax for creating an object, which isn't what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

use backticks

```css
className={     



`${active?"eexpand":null  }`}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answers above suggest, this will work:

```
className={"collapse" + active ?  "expand" : null}
```

But I would actually suggest using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) because it's more clean and performant.

This would look as such:

```
className={`collapse ${active ?  "expand" : ""}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template strings such as:

```
className={`collapse ${active ?  "expand" : ""}`}
```

But I recommend [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) library:

```
className={ clsx( 'collapse', active && 'expand' ) };
```